# Powershell Start-Process on shared drive

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, network-drive, start-process

I am trying to run a .msi that is in a network folder on my local machine. If I do it this way it means that I only have to update the file in one spot.

The issue I run into is that I keep getting invalid username/password errors. 
I put in domain/username and the appropriate password when it prompts for it

```
$domaincred = Get-Credential


start-process -filepath "\\ofs1\shared\admin\original\screenconnect\Mity-Corporate.msi" -ArgumentList /quiet -Credential $domaincred
```

I know that this works fine if I run it on a local machine (from my C drive) but that defeats the purpose of what I am building.

I apologize if this is a stupid question but I am a little newer to powershell and it is very finicky

Comment: Unclear from what you've provided since you say it works fine on local machine.  so where does it not work fine?  this perhaps --- search for powershell pssession double hop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way that I found is by mapping the drive with "New-PSDrive" and then working through the newly created drive. This gets you around the issues surrounding using credentials on "Start-Process"

Example:

```
$domaincred = Get-Credential

New-PSDrive -Name "Z" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root 
        "\\server\folder" -Credential $domaincred

start-process -filepath "Z:\filename.msi" -ArgumentList /quiet
```